# List all tables with a specific column Name

Tags: sql, db2, dbeaver

i didn't find the right answear here. So I work with a lot of different tables. The Schema of the Tables are `GDBADMP.[Table_Name]` or `USCH1060.[Table_Name]`.

Now i search a way to list all tables with an exact column Name like `PLZ_ID`. The column contains different values, somtimes `varchar` or `int`

Like: `Show all Tables (GDBADMP.[Table_Name]) with the column Name PLZ_ID`

**My first thoughts are like this:**

```
SELECT *
FROM GDBADMP.*
WHERE PLZ_ID
```

Kind regards

Comment: What is `PLZ_ID`? Is this a column name which all your tables of interest have? If yes, then what's the column value you use? Something like `PLZ_ID = 1`? If no, then please, edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I added more information!

Comment: Look at the [syscat.columns](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-syscatcolumns) catalog view. You may join it to syscat.tables by (tabschema, tabname) to get tables only (excluding views, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Look at the syscat.columns catalog view. You may join it to syscat.tables by (tabschema, tabname) to get tables only (excluding views, for example).

Thanks to this comment. I found a solution!

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS a
WHERE a.colname = 'PLZ_ID'
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS which is a system table that contains all the fields in all tables.

Below a sample query that will return the tables in a form of creator.table:

```
SELECT TRIM(TBCREATOR)||'.'||TRIM(TBNAME) AS FULLTABLE
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE NAME='PLZ_ID'
```